# How to get contract multiplier in pine script - Trading View

Tags: pine-script

I'm working on indicator which will show how many contracts to trade and what is the stop lost and take profit.
The only problem as of now I was not able to solve is how to get contract multiplier in pine-script.

**Example**: When you trade $CL (Light Sweet Cure Oil) futures it will show you price $65.39 which at the time of trading one contract for $CL you need to multiple $65.39 times 1000 pcs (this is the minimum per contract). But if trade another ticker say $ZS there is multiplier is 50 pcs per contract.

Please if anyone knows how to get this qty in pine-script study or if there is any other solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We answered you in the Pine Script chat already. Don't ask the same question in multiple forums. You risk getting different volunteers helping you concurrently.

> You can usually get it from `syminfo.pointvalue`:
> [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_syminfo{dot}pointvalue](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dpointvalue)
> You can also see the value in the symbol's more menu, under "Symbol info".